# How to have rules for every single different input in a Pythonic way?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's the best way to change the course of action for each possible response to a query?

For example at the moment if I wanted to do this I'd do:

```
list_of_answers = ["One answer", "Another", "One more", "Yet another"]
print(list_of_answers)
user_input = input("Choose from the above list")

if user_input = "One answer":
   #do this

elif user_input = "Another":
  #do that
...

#etc, etc
```

This is fine for the example provided, but if I had say 20 possible choices, I don't want a huge block of `if this... that, elif this... that`.

I was wondering if there was a Pythonic way of doing things of this sort?

Comment: Make dict with choices and if k in dict do v.

Comment: Another option is to use one of those dispatch modules such as singledispatch.

Comment: @DanD. I don't think you can use Python's single dispatch on string literals (or any constants at all)?

Comment: @KacperFloriański Right. singledispatch doesn't support constants. I think that one of the extended ones does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to work with a pythonic implementation of a "branch table" for this kind of scenario. It looks really clean, and you can add options easily.

```py
HANDLERS = {"One answer": handle_one_answer, "Another": handle_second_answer}

def handle_one_answer():
    pass

def handle_second_answer():
    pass

def default_handler():
    pass

def main():
    print(HANDLERS.keys())
    user_input = input("Choose from the above list")
    HANDLERS.get(user_input, default_handler)()
```